# What to do with the "rm -rf" hoax question

Tags: discussion

It turns out the the [recent question](https://serverfault.com/questions/769357/recovering-from-a-rm-rf) regarding the misuse of `rm -rf` in Ansible was actually just a [hoax](http://www.repubblica.it/tecnologia/2016/04/15/news/cancella_l_azienda_per_sbaglio_la_disavventura_tecnologica_di_marco_marsala-137693154/?ref=twhr&timestamp=1460722285000&utm_source=dlvr.it&utm_medium=twitter) ([English](http://www.snopes.com/man-deletes-company-code/)) in some kind of viral marketing effort. It become quite famous on various media and gathered a large number of views.

Since I don't think we should allow ServerFault to be abused in such way, I deleted the question once I learned about the hoax. However, this will rob the kind people that took the time to answer him of the rep points they earned for this, in particular the [Journeyman Geek](https://serverfault.com/users/33193/journeyman-geek) with 185 upvotes.

So, how should we deal with this question? Vote below.

---

There is a clear majority towards merging the question into [this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/587102/monday-morning-mistake-sudo-rm-rf-no-preserve-root). I'll do this now.

Comment: Have we had any input from community@stack?

Comment: Was the question a valid and useful question for server fault? If so why does it matter what the motivations of the asker were? Stack exchange is about building a Q and A for the public at large.

Comment: @MartinSmith no - it was a duplicate. The original poster said in a recent article it was " a guerrilla marketing operation" so blatant spam/troll.

Comment: For those, like me, left high and dry because we aren't yet at 10k, google does have a cache of most of the page content: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fserverfault.com%2Fquestions%2F769357%2Frecovering-from-a-rm-rf&oq=cache%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fserverfault.com%2Fquestions%2F769357%2Frecovering-from-a-rm-rf&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS647US647&ie=UTF-8&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.2895j0j7&sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.&bvm=bv.119745492,d.dmo&biw=1605&bih=1584&dpr=1&ech=1&psi=_hsRV4PBJ4S5eazhpegN.1460738942251.3&ei=_hsRV4PBJ4S5eazhpegN&emsg=NCSR&noj=1

Comment: Side question: why were my comments to this question deleted, and only mine (other comments are still there)? They were neither spam nor off-topic, as I was remarking the importance of proper backups and how being able at all to delete everything with a single command implied fundamental design flaws, rather than simple bad luck.

Comment: @Massimo there are a _lot_ of deleted comments on that post. Not just yours. As to why they were deleted, I'm unsure.

Comment: Deleting as dup seems wrong. I don't have an opinion on what to do. Maybe just keep deleted but, how can something be a duplicated question if it was a FORGED situation? The problem didn't even existed at first place...

Comment: @MarkHenderson Fine, I can't see deleted comments at all; however, one of mine ("I won't even begin enumerating how many errors are simultaneously required in order to be able to completely erase all your servers and all your backups in a single strike. This is not bad luck: it's astonishingly bad design reinforced by complete carelessness.”) was upvoted a lot and even cited in the Independent article talking about the fact; I just wonder what logic exactly led to its deletion.

Comment: For the records, I don't know this guy and I don't have any relationship with him; and I sincerely hope whoever deleted my comments didn't do that on such an implication, possibly having seen how we both are from the same country.

Comment: @Massimo Oh I think that is _highly_ unlikely. Lots of people are from the same country!

Comment: @Massimo From what I know (which isn't much), a lot of the moderation tools around comments are designed for bulk deletion of comments. Oftentimes innocent comments are caught in the crossfire.

Comment: The mobile version of the news story appears to not display the full article. For me, it stops at the paragraph mentioning "140k persone", and I cannot find an option to display the full article. This is important because the content *after* that paragraph contains the admission of this Q&A existing as part of an effort to advertise his startup.

Comment: Someone with a lot of time on their hands could contact all the [news outlets which have run this story](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=nws&q=%22Marco%20Marsala%22) and advise them of the situation.

Comment: It even made it into a german newspaper (http://www.sueddeutsche.de/digital/rm-rf-eine-falsche-zeile-code-und-die-firma-ist-vernichtet-1.2951895). They missed the `/` in the `rm -rf /` tho.

Comment: @MichaelHampton It's actually shocking to see how "respectable" newspapers have run this story as fact, without any research (like trying to find the name of the company he works for or any of the websites affected). But it is at least a good demonstration of which news sources cannot be trusted.

Comment: The hoax author seems to mouth off against SE users in the newspaper article for not catching him at his hoax. Can anyone with more italian knowledge than my google translate skills verify this? I think this would make a dangerous precedent (@Massimo ?)

Comment: @dualed Not only against SE; looks like he posted the same fake request for help to other sites, too; this was one of the few place where someone actually catched something didn't smell right. And yes, in his interviews he shows a "you all fell for this and I'm **SO** smart" attitude which is IMHO quite childish.

Comment: Is there an english write up article on how this was revealed?

Comment: @Massimo we went into it thinking he was an idiot. We've came out of it thinking he's an idiot, but for a different reason. I don't think the joke is on us.

Comment: Since we didn't delete, you should unaccept the delete answer.

Comment: @AaronHall:  I did merge the questions. This doesn't delete it outright though, but if you come here as an anonymous user, you get redirected to the merge target immediately and never see the hoax question.

Comment: @AaronHall Only the person who asked the question can accept or unaccept an answer.

Comment: Maybe the comments to journeymans answer should be cleaned up as well. the OP talks about recovering the data via a company which analyzed their discs, which I guess is not quite true. Will any moderator take a look at it or should I flag those which I feel are untrue?

Comment: At least use a better link to an article explaining the hoax.  The current link points to an Italian website.  Here's [one in English](http://www.snopes.com/man-deletes-company-code/).  I don't think many people here are fluent in Italian?

Comment: Something tells me that this isn't a hoax. He's just covering it up to save the reputation of his company.

Comment: @gldraphael I wonder if it could possibly be connected to this story of a real UK hosting company who did very recently accidentally delete the entire contents of several servers: http://www.bbc.com/news/technology-36072240

Comment: @aroth At the time of the posting it was the only article, because the publication had direct contact with the author. The link you shared was posted two days after this meta topic, and no one was stopping you from clicking on the *edit* link. :)

Comment: @AndrewB - I'm pretty sure I don't have enough rep on serverfault to click the 'edit' link?  The only option it gives me is 'share'.  @gldraphael - You may be right.  Or at least, his claim that "the command that I mentioned in the article is harmless", where the command is `rm -rf /`, seems to be false.  Unless Ansible really does prevent that sort of thing?  I have no idea if it does, but seems a bit far-fetched to think that it would?

Comment: @aroth Hrm, my apologies then. I did look at the permissions list and I thought you'd at least have enough to suggest an edit. (just not enough to apply it directly)

Comment: Question for a mod/community manager, any update if we nuke the account ? as it seem a option the community want.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: (unrelated to the conversation) you may want to add a Google Translation link (https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=it&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.repubblica.it%2Ftecnologia%2F2016%2F04%2F15%2Fnews%2Fcancella_l_azienda_per_sbaglio_la_disavventura_tecnologica_di_marco_marsala-137693154%2F&edit-text=) for the article in Italian you linked in the (now locked) question.

Comment: What's the proof that the question was a hoax? The italian article doesn't show any "proof".

Comment: @Mzn: He admitted it in a mod message.

Comment: @Sven, that's enough proof for moderation purposes. But what kind of publicity is one that shows how BAD and risky it is to get services from that service provider? Maybe his confession is what is false, and he is trying to undo his mistake of showing everyone that his company isn't following best practices. Maybe he wasn't expecting publicity. Just a hypothesis.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

It was closed as a dupe. Delete the hoax and keep the dupe. Consider merging the answers from the hoax into it. Remember SF is for practical problems you are trying to solve. A hoax by definition isn't this.

Comment: If the answers can be made to fit the dup-target, this is reasonable.

Comment: Why merge answers from a question that was a hoax? I don't think this could help any serious question, by merging answers that came from questions that are a lie!

Comment: @nwildner This isn't the first time we've seen "Halp, I deleted all my things, what do I do?!?!?", (or even the more specific Linux/rm -rf variant) and it won't be the last.  So, next time, we can point to the question and say "nope, you're screwed, like this guy.  And that guy.  And that guy, and..." That's how it helps.

Comment: Yeah, but if `rm -fr /` will not work, there is no need to "document" this, and use as proof to other questions since they will not show something real, and could be hoaxes too

Comment: @nwildner I was being somewhat `pink-and-fluffy`; people are more likely to react well to something that preserves content and UIPs than to the thermonuclear option of deleting the whole mess (which I'd quite happily do too)... Anyway that's my last word on the matter if you want to continue discussing this with the noob please to it $elsewhere.

Comment: I just disagree on merging answers. That's why i also gave a suggestion below :) Mark as spam, edit to explain the hoax and let the question closed. This way will preserve content and avoid mixing true answers with anwers of a question that was a lie :P

Comment: @nwildner: It will work with non-GNU rm. So i guess with FreeBSD you're out of luck with the same problem. Too lazy to fire up a vm just to test it, but most real unices do not prevent you from doing stupid things.

Comment: Deleting is bad - too many outside sources are pointing to it. Edit it, declare it's a hoax, and lock it. Or redirect the page to this page.

Comment: @allo That used to be true, but don't assume it still is: https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/commit/d6b7bd90c2776d9ccd8bb7f33a899bd213aebf85

Comment: The question was closed before I was able to answer.  If they had used `set -u` in their shell script, the faux problem would not have occured.  Setting `set-u` will cause bash to exit, due to unbound variables.  `rm -Rf ${foo}/${bar}`

Answer (score 113):

Consider Nuking the OP's account too. Anything less will just encourage other marketing stunts like this.

Comment: Agreed. Push the big red button.

Comment: This I disagree with. A single transgression does not warrant this.

Comment: Permlock his account but keep it around.  Edit the profile description with a link to this Meta question with the words "Don't be like this guy"

Comment: @MarkHenderson - http://www.businesspundit.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/10/despair-poster-mistakes.jpg

Comment: @MarkHenderson If this were a mistake? or April Fools then I would agree with you but it's neither. It is a deliberate act and should be punished as such.

Comment: @Iain Show me where it says that moderators can unilaterally delete someone's entire account based on their own discretion.

Comment: Sufficient upvotes might get it done though because that's the community's wish.

Comment: @Iain moderators do not enforce the community's wish. They enforce the rules.

Comment: I think we're going to have to agree to disagree on that.

Comment: Way to over react. Personally I doubt it warrants a suspension let alone account deletion.

Comment: Bit late for that; question and user have had a fairly insane amount of attention already; best to make the truth known.

Comment: He changed his profile name in the meantime; probably some of that attention backfired. Looks like you don't really get good publicity for your company by telling the world "I accidentally nuked all my servers and data"... even if it wasn't true, it's still *quite* unprofessional.

Comment: @MarkHenderson As he spammed I would atleast block him on SF, aka a ban.

Comment: @yagmoth555 That was *not* spam; if you think it was, then you need to revise your definition. It was a troll, but there are no rules specific to that so it's down to the situation and mod discussion to decide what to do.

Comment: @Iain Account deletion is not a proportional, reasoned response to someone taking the mick. It's overkill and petty revenge for a perceived slight that has only affected *the OP* negatively; the site itself has *gained* traffic and users from it.

Comment: @ArtOfCode I'm going to give you the benefit of the doubt and assume that you read the mobile version of the story. By the poster's own admission this was part of an attempt to advertise his startup. The content of the Q&A itself may not be spam, but it *exists* for the purpose of commercial self-promotion, and therefore meets the definition.

Comment: @ArtOfCode I note with interested sadness your complete lack of prior  involvement with community and give your comment the contempt it deserves.

Comment: @iain that doesn't make his point any less valid.

Comment: @Mark I understand that this topic is important to you, but can you *please* pick your examples better? I've respected your stance up until now, but the idea that only the OP suffered here is demonstrably false. Some of the coverage this has gotten left people on mailing lists that I frequent with the impression that we're too stupid to understand what block level recovery is.

Comment: @AndrewB I didn't say he was right. I just said that his opinion isn't invalid.

Comment: As for people saying we are too stupid to understand block level recovery, that is 100% our fault. We write smartass smug answers and we reap what we sow.

Comment: Imagine the great publicity we could have got if more people wrote answers like Journeymans, and were way less dickish in the comments

Comment: @Mark In an industry that thrives on selective quoting, I don't buy *"100% our fault"*. We own our share of the blame, sure, but the rest of the blame belongs to anyone who specifically chooses to use those remarks as representative over the highest upvoted answers. As such, harm still occurred. (and this by no means endorses smarmy remarks that are wrong)

Comment: @AndrewB they couldn't have selectively chosen smartass comments if there were none to choose.

Comment: @Mark We're splitting hairs here. Yes, it could be better. I can get behind being better. But zero snarky quips? On the internet? Without moderator intervention? You're using an unreachable ideal to mince a point, and I'm not going to go down this rabbit hole all night.

Comment: @MarkHenderson Why you fear what other think ? You bring the debate somewhere else. The problem of how the community react is another debate (like peterh's critic in the past) The problem there is that if you let someone use other on SF it's simply a lack of respect. I help by donating my time, does you endorse that someone start hoaxing question to advertise is own stuff ? That hoax got more view than all of my help over 1 year.. so yes, maybe SF is a great advertising platform now.

Comment: @yagmoth555 at no stage did I say there should be no repercussions! I just do not support this specific nuclear option, as there is no precedent to justify doing so.

Comment: @MarkHenderson oh ok, well for me as iam not a native english I maybe mistinerpreted the option, as nuking for me only meaned a ban on all se's site, sorry if I misinterpreted your opinion.

Comment: @Iain lack of involvement with the community is probably an advantage here in reaching an impartial and objective view. Some of you seem to be taking this far too personally and blowing things way out of proportion.

Comment: @MartinSmith That only show that we should open a another question of how to react to the user and move that Answer there. As everyone in comment there approve something, but not all for the same thing.

Comment: @Iain this community, sure. Now go look up my network profile. I'm rather well acquainted with moderator action policies, I'm afraid. I give your retort much the same contempt.

Comment: Delete the account, but allow to re-register under another name. You cannot prevent people from registering new pseudonyms anyway and the karma loss and loss of known nickname should be enough.

Comment: I don't think it matters if he gets banned- as long as we know who he is when he posts. On that note, banning is a purely symbolic act that tells whoever you've banned that you're butthurt and want them to have to enter the registration details again. No real damage, except maybe to reputation of post history content, is done. So let's stop arguing about this like it's a "nuclear" option.

Comment: @MarkHenderson Every mod and ex-mod on here has deleted multiple spammer accounts, so let's not pretend this is without precedent.  He's made 11 other posts, only 3 of which have a positive score.  Not exactly a pillar of the community, and not the first time a minor contributor decided to go spammer, and got deleted accordingly. A handful of upvotes haven't protected other spammers, and they shouldn't protect this one either.  (To say nothing of the giant middle finger he gave us that run-of-the-mill spammers don't.)

Comment: @HopelessN00b then you should remember the checkbox you have to select when nuking a spammer. And the text saying that it's primarily a spam account. This account is not an account that was created explicitly for spamming. This account _was_ in good standing and could return to good standing in the future.

Comment: @MarkHenderson Excluding the hoax question, he's got 11 posts with a combined net score of -2.  His spam post got 190k views, and has a current score of +9.  Sure sounds to me like his account's primary contribution is spam.

Comment: Again, it doesn't matter- if he comes back, he will likely use a new account to avoid looking stupid. Banned or not. Don't waste more brain cells arguing about the finer interpretation pointss of the rules.

Comment: @HopelessN00b except... Where's the bit that he spammed? Where did he actually post an advertisement _on our site_? Also basil is correct, at this point in time it's just wasting bits to discuss it further.

Comment: @MarkHenderson Yeah, right.  And the moral of the story is:  feel free to use SF as a platform for your viral spamming campaign, because you'll get a week's suspension, even if the community is 8:1 in favor of treating a spammer like a spammer.

Comment: @HopelessN00b failing to see the downside of that, assuming that the question isn't horrible.

Comment: @MarkHenderson for a spammer the repercusion you told me is a week ban ?? wow. *facepalm*

Comment: @HopelessN00b I extremely doubt that SF will suddenly become the platform for any further "viral marketing" as a result of this. I doubt any potential customers were impressed by the antics of the OP. And if it did then prospective viral marketeers would just know to open a throw away account in the future anyway.

Comment: @MartinSmith 'first post' review queue exist for that to leverage the spam detection & rate. The user got a lot of view, is hoax worked. Next thing is what, posting valid questions about a startup product to get it know ?

Comment: @yagmoth555 sigh. There is no one week ban for spammers. Spamming is an insta-kill. But this was _not spam_. The only rule that he actually broke what what we used to call "not a real question", but essentially you're only meant to ask questions about problems you've _actually_ had. And that isn't even enforced very rigorously. I agree this was a dick move, but I really don't see why everyone is so furious about it.

Comment: @yagmoth555 That "startup" thing you mentioned, some people have [already tried it before](http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/g-wan). That's astrotufing. This was not that either.

Comment: @MarkHenderson for me it fit Andrew B comment to ArtofCode for the definition of spam. We simply just dont agree into that point.

Comment: @ArtOfCode "...the site itself has gained traffic and users from it..." I'm pretty sure BuzzFeed and other clickbait sites think the same way. Do we want to be better than them (quality), or do we only care about page views (quantity)?

Comment: @MarkHenderson "I agree this was a dick move, but I really don't see why everyone is so furious about it." We are furious about it because *not doing something about a dick move* tells everyone that *dick moves are okay*. And they absolutely are not.

Comment: @IanKemp there have been plenty of dickheads doing dickheadish things on this site before and we've never. Ever. Had this level of outrage over it. I also never said we shouldn't do anything about it. I think the action that was taken now is 100% the correct action (merge, leave a message). Everyone is just super passionate about this particular dickhead suggesting all sorts of nuclear options that are, in my mind, unreasonable and over the top.

Comment: @MarkHenderson I seen a user with over 3k points on SF that got banned for 1 year for beeing a dickhead, while that dickhead got a week ban. Downplaying that dickhead is not fair either.

Comment: @yagmoth555 If someone gets banned _for an entire year_, then it's not a first offence. It means that they have had repeated warnings and ignored them. Suspensions are escalating, so to reach a 1 year ban means they've had multiple shorter bans and continued their behaviour.

Comment: Why is everyone getting so hung up on the spam argument? It's much more simple than that. From the ToS (emphasis mine): "Under no circumstances will Subscriber use the Network or the Service to ... ***(d) knowingly post any false, inaccurate or incomplete material***..."

Comment: Also: "Any ***fraudulent***, abusive, or otherwise illegal activity or any use of the Services or Content in violation of this Agreement may be grounds for termination of Subscriber’s right to Services or to access the Network." Now, to be fair, the verbiage is "***may*** be grounds for termination". Still, I agree this is a rather offensive case as demonstrated by - if nothing else - the votes in this thread.

Answer (score 55):

Undelete the question and edit it to explain the situation.

Comment: The big advantage of this is since this question has had a lot of attention, if people follow the links back, least they know what happened. On the other hand, they'll know this guy didn't actually delete his entire company's data. On the gripping hand, I'm not sure that his 'official' excuse - that its a viral stunt, makes him look much better.

Comment: I would add a bit about this on top of the merged question to explain what happened.

Comment: Deleting the question makes it pretty obvious what happened, too.

Comment: you would think so but I've seen comments on "news" articles about this which mention the deletion but assume it was because the feedback on the problem got too "brutal" (whatever that's meant to mean) and not because it was a hoax

Comment: @RоryMcCune I don't think that's what anyone really wants, and given that, I've undeleted the question for the time being.

Comment: @Michael With that perception of brutal feedback in mind, you might also want to edit the "f*****" part out. While that was sufficient for "internal documentation" purposes, people who aren't going to run that URL through a translator need to understand that this was a publicity stunt.

Comment: @AndrewB Done. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Do you know what happened to my comments, especially the one that had several upvotes and was even quoted in the Independent article? I don't understand why they were deleted, and I'd like them back, if possible; also, I'd really like to know why they have been deleted, while others have not.

Comment: @Massimo A Stack Overflow employee deleted your comments. I don't know exactly why, but I can guess. As some news outlets noted, they weren't exactly helpful...

Comment: @MichaelHampton Well, I was remarking (on the assumption he was not a troll) how you need a really flawed setup to be able to delete all your servers, all your data and ***all your backups*** with a single command; that was not to be blamed on a mistake or bad luck, but on an astonishing series of design and implementation errors. And it looks like my remark was on point, because IIRC last time I saw it, it had 15 upvotes...

Answer (score 41):

Undelete the question, mark it as a dupe, add a note, and lock it.

It has a significant number of inbound links, and a lot of traffic right now.  Deleting it leaves these links broken, "Page Not Found" to the vast majority of viewers.

Marking it as a duplicate directs users to the more pertinent real question, while not denying people the opportunity to read and laugh at the hoax.

Locking it prevents any further issues with it.

Further, even hoax questions can provide some value, and there is a lot of value in the answers, even if they can't be moved as-is to the new question.

Lastly, those who spent time giving great answers are not denied the reputation gained, but once locked also won't continue to see their reputation climb due to the popularity of the question versus the value of their answer.

Comment: Merging will redirect links to the merge target, so they are not broken.

Comment: @Sven I don't believe the duplicate is exact - one is about getting access to a possibly still running system, the other is about recovering data. If there were an exact duplicate, then I'd be with you, but even then it's not as good a solution as undeleting and closing as dupe.

Answer (score 28):

His account should be deleted, and the question should be heavily edited in content, along with a warning message explaining what happened.

I'll outline why I think so:

His hoax post in itself has the following issues:

- it abuses free help
- he claimed basically that people answering are stupid for not noticing he didn't show the GNU option that'd catch his error

  - that lacks relevance because humans trying to help someone who made a mistake will often assume he made more than the one he's showing around
  - there is a lot of operating systems, even linux-based ones where it'd have worked
- he violates ethical standards for systems administrators. as such it's a pity he's holding the job. we don't just got technical requirements but also a certain code to work by.

**intentionally misleading** people fails that code. even more so if it is for "marketing purposes"

- he fails to even thank people
- he failed to understand that people tried to help him and assumed we don't spot his error (while the dupe pointed to no-preserve-root case, making obvious to a sane person that mods assumed he DID run that and was just too stupid to properly give his example
- he's also not aware older ansible versions might have let him come away with empty vars (iirc that's the case if you go back 2 years in versions)

Finally, I also think if this is not stopped now, we will get a larger problem. A much larger one.
This is a very similar story as the first spam message ever, which went to usenet and didn't get policed hard enough.
That is why we have spam now. it goes back over 20 years because some company got away with it.

Delete the guy's account and email him that he is to never come back unless he vows to act in a manner that respects this place.
He spit in SO's face and there's no reason to keep him around.

And *most definitely* not the question if we lose rep. over it.

IMO the most important answer in the thread was the one "you need a lawyer", pointing him at the point where you need to interrupt technical measures for business measures to not totally fail in compliance.
I felt really sorry for this poor guy trying to fix it on a technical level where he has to let go and come out.

IMO duping is not really enough, since the linked question iirc concerned only one server whereas he pretended to have taken out everything. (system failure vs. everything failure)

As for verification in news etc.: I found out enough that he's working in some isp context and his past questions weren't super-duped skilled, so it was plausible. I tried to verify via webhostingtalk if there's any outcries from affected customers but a) italy isn't well represented there b) there's always a few dead incompetent ISP's.
This makes it kinda futile - this guy assumes we should have caught him on it when we just tried to calm someone who was (pretense) completely out of their depth.

That, in my mind, shows he's not really a kind person anyway. 
I don't him around here and much less so I want his "marketing" to be a thing we encounter again. They can buy adspace for that.

As a sysadmin I feel insulted by the fact he thinks he's doing the same job.

Comment: +1, The last sentence really sums it all.

Comment: +1.  He's a spammer.  The fact that he has a handful of upvotes from a handful of other posts doesn't change that.  We delete spammers' accounts all the time, and should dispose of this spammer in the same manner we dispose of other spammers.

Comment: May the fleas from a thousand camels take up residence in his pubic hair.

Answer (score 13):

Option 3, disassociate the question from the user.  Lets the question and its useful answers stay around, and denies this troll the promotional value of his little experiment in viral trolling.

Comment: I can't do this without deleting the user, but since this wasn't his only post, I don't want to do this. I really like Iain's approach, which I hadn't considered.

Comment: Nuke the user, it's the only way to be sure.

Comment: @Sven You can ask the SE devs to do it.  They've done it for me for a lot less, so I imagine they'd be willing to do it for you, given that this impacts other users and is a documented hoax at this point.

Comment: This gets into weird situations WRT the content license; normally we only disassociate upon author request, and only when deletion isn't desirable. Dup'd or merged, the question serves as a useful redirect to the original, which could actually do some good as a public-service message of sorts here.

Answer (score 9):

Edit the question, don't delete it. The great thing about Stack Exchange is that we have the ability to turn bad questions into good ones.

It doesn't matter that the story isn't *true*; the problem with this question is that the story is *irrelevant*. It can be improved by removing the details that are both useless and false.

> I accidentally ran `rm -rf /` on multiple machines, deleting everything on them (including offsite backups because the remote storage was mounted).
>
> How I can recover from a `rm -rf /` now in a timely manner?

Answer (score 5):

How do we deal with actual spam? This is actual spam, and should be treated the same way.

Answer (score 4):

Simply deleting the question might actually teach a lesson everyone who decided to make a story off a simple question on a Q/A website, without even considering the possibility that the claims in the original post might be inaccurate (though I am pretty sure they have). Even if there was no ill intent involved it's still a duplicate of a question which has been asked countless times on ServerFault and many other websites on the StackExchange network. The popularity of the thread and countless websites linking to it should not warrant any exceptions in this case.

As for punishing the author, I don't think his motivations should be grounds for actually punishing him in any way as long as his question adhered to the rules. And I believe it did, except for the duplication part.

Answer (score 4):

So, this question would have absolutely nothing to do with [this actual situation](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/technology-36072240)?

It sounds to me as if the OP was pancaking in his message when I read the question, the comments also clarify him trying to cover his backside.  The change of his profile is likely to protect his employability in future given that majority of employers will use Stack Exchange and source developers from it.  Especially senior engineers who will conduct the interviews.

In which case there were two points that I think would benefit people and reasons for why this question shouldn't be deleted.

1. Someone raised a valid questions about the `--no-preserve-root` and a comment suggesting this is valid only for new versions of Linux from 2012 (or something)
2. Although there is no solution to a physical deletion without any form of back-up giving answers that can assist in snapshots, back-up procedures etc would be very beneficial.

Answer (score 3):

Keep the question deleted. This has no place here at all.

Comment: It was closed as a dupe. Delete the hoax and keep the dupe. Consider merging the answers from the hoax into it. Remember SF is for practical problems you are trying to solve. A hoax by definition isn't this.

Comment: Oh @Iain - such wisdom thou hast.  Has?  doth hast?  +1

Comment: @TheCleaner "Thou hast" or "thou dost have". Never "thou doth hast". ("doth" is for third person singular - I do, thou dost, he/she doth.)

Comment: @JennyD I thought you were Swedish!  How camest thou by such command of Shakespearean English?

Comment: @MadHatter I am. I read a lot, including Shakespeare....

Comment: @JennyD congratulations on a grasp of period English that probably exceeds that of 95% of those native to the sceptred isle.  I knew we Brits were comparitively poorly grounded in other people's languages, but this is just embarrassing.

Comment: @MadHatter Well, I started out as a language major, I didn't get into IT until I was in my mid-20's.

Comment: @JennyD I always remember this by way of German: "Ich habe, du hast, er hat -> I have, thou hast, he hath".

Answer (score 3):

Edit the question so other sites that created news based on this thread can double-check the information, mark as spam, since the definition of spam on SE is self-promotion:

> Exists only to promote a product or service, does not disclose the author's affiliation.

If he was looking for viral marketing attention, this is nothing but spam.

Comment: Marking as spam results in auto-deletion.